# How to properly setup and get Guzzle client object values in Laravel constructor?

Tags: laravel, guzzle, guzzle6

I have a `Laravel` controller which contains several functions (for API calls) which uses  [guzzlephp.org](http://guzzlephp.org)  for external calls to our partner's API. I want to initialize the `$client` object to be uniformly used to all of the functions that might needed it. I set it like this:

```
private $client;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(
        ['base_url' => env('PARTNER_API_URL')],
        ['defaults' => [
            'auth' => [env('PARTNER_UNAME'), env('PARTNER_PWORD')]
        ]]
    );
}
```

Now my problem here is that when I try to call a function that uses the `guzzle client` object, it is not reading or getting the values I set in the constructor. An example of a function that I call is this:

```
public function getPersonData(Request $request){

    $person_id = $request->input('person_id');

    try {
        $res = $this->client->get('/person/data?person_id='.$person_id);   
    }
    catch (GuzzleException $e) {

        return $e;
    }

    $response = $res->getBody();

    return $response;
}
```

It returns an exception with this error:
`RuntimeException: Error creating resource: [message] fopen(person/data?person_id=111034): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

How to properly setup the `guzzle` client in the constructor of a Laravel controller to be used in the functions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you pointed to, the parameter should be `base_uri`, not `base_url`.
http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://httpbin.org']);
```